# What is the term for the smallest number that two numbers can both divide into evenly?

Tags: terminology

For example, for the numbers $2$ and $3$ it would be $6$, which is the smallest number that's evenly divisible by both $2$ and $3$.

More examples: for $10$ and $40$ it would be $40$. For $7$ and $11$ it would be $77$. For $3$ and $5$ it would be $15$. For $250$ and $375$ it would be $750$.

Comment: Least common multiple.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is [least common multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple). Any number that $250$ divides evenly into is called a *multiple* of $250$. And any number that $375$ divides evenly into is called a multiple of $375$. The two numbers necessarily have some multiples in common, and $750$ is the smallest (positive) such number. Hence the phrase *least common multiple*.